# Why does <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> include all my JS files in development but not in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

My `application.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails.validations
//= require_tree .
```

My development site has this in the source:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails.validations.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/industries.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ba-hashchange-v1.3.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.flexslider-v1.8.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/main-r6.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But my production looks like this:

```
<script src="/assets/application-b5f7c629f9622da89d5cc703e459e6c3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My `config/environments/development.rb` has this:

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

My `config/environments/production.rb` has this:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false    
  config.assets.compress = true    
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Thoughts?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html - both environments are including all the javascript, but in production it's being combined/minified into a single file (application.js).

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Thanks. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both environments are including all the javascript. By default in production mode the rails asset pipeline combines/minifies your javascript (and css), this reduces the amount of requests the browser/client needs to make to the server.

There's a detailed explanation of the asset pipeline in the rails guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html